# Compute a sum in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `m` by `n` matrix `A`, implemented as a `numpy` array.

```
import numpy as np
m = 10
n = 7
A = np.random.rand(m, n)
```

I want to compute the `m` by `m` matrix `B` whose entries are

```
B[i, j] = sum_{k=1,...,n} sum_{l=1,...,n} A[i, k] * A[j, l]
```

What is the easiest way to do this without making explicit for loops?

Comment: Show your loopy code?

Comment: @Divakar See edit.

Comment: .. `A.dot(A.T)`?

Comment: @SimonParker the code in your edit does not compute `sum_{k} sum_{l} A[i, k] * A[j, l]`, but `sum_{k} A[i, k] * A[j, k]`, which @Divakar's `A.dot(A.T)` gives you.

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso That's a mistake. The first version was the good one. I will erase it.

Comment: Well, the first version isn't clear to me. At least provide a sample and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the sum over `k` in your expression only affects the first factor, while the sum over `l` only involves the second:

```
sum_{k=1,...,n} sum_{l=1,...,n} A[i, k] * A[j, l] =
    (sum_{k=1,...,n}  A[i, k]) * (sum_{l=1,...,n} A[j, l])
```

The expressions in parentheses are, except for the names of the indices, the same, so define

```
sA = np.sum(A, axis=1)
```

Then your `B` is the so-called [outer product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) of `sA` with itself:

```
B = np.outer(sA, sA)
```